# Ubuntu Installer doesn't recognize my partitions

Tags: partitioning, system-installation, hard-drive, gparted

I'm trying to dual boot Ubuntu 13.10 along with Win8.1.
The problem here is Ubuntu installer does not recognize any of my partitions and shows my whole hdd space as unallocated. That is the case with GParted also.
The tricky part is that the Ubuntu itself (in Live mode) is perfectly capable of recognizing and mounting the partitions.

I did a little searching and came up with [this solution](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1793978&p=11008704#post11008704) but I can not be sure that it applies to my problem too as I can not risk loosing my Windows installation.

**UPDATE:** The result of mount:

```
/dev/sda2 on /media/ubuntu/585084B850849DFE type fuseblk (rw,nosuid,nodev,allow_other,default_permissions,blksize=4096)
/dev/sda3 on /media/ubuntu/Linux type fuseblk (rw,nosuid,nodev,allow_other,default_permissions,blksize=4096)
/dev/sda5 on /media/ubuntu/Linux Home type fuseblk (rw,nosuid,nodev,allow_other,default_permissions,blksize=4096)
/dev/sda6 on /media/ubuntu/Misc type fuseblk (rw,nosuid,nodev,allow_other,default_permissions,blksize=4096)
```

**UPDATE 2:** Upong running GParted I get the following message:

> /dev/sda contains GPT signatures, indicating that it has a GPT table. 
>   However, it does not have a valid fake msdos partition table, as it
>   should.  Perhaps it was corrupted -- possibly by a program that
>   doesn't understand GPT partition tables.  Or perhaps you deleted the
>   GPT table, and are now using an msdos partition table.  Is this a GPT
>   partition table?

And here is a screenshot from GParted.
[image]

Comment: Did you try formatting your unallocated space to ext4?

Comment: @NGRhodes My box does not support Secure boot and that question doesn't apply to my case.

Comment: @Mr.Lee I don't want my space formatted. I mentioned that I need my Windows installation.

Comment: Hmm, post your LiveCD gparted tables.

Comment: If ubuntu in live mode recognizes the partitions correctly, did you try starting the installer from live mode? You can do so by just choosing “Try Ubuntu” and then starting the installer from the launcher shortcut.

Comment: @Donarsson Yes I did. I found the solution and will post it shortly.

Comment: This question is *not* a duplicate of the "Installing Ubuntu..." question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed the problem easily using the [FixParts](http://www.rodsbooks.com/fixparts/) package. It simply removed the leftover GPT data on the HDD from the previous partitioning.